# php how to dynamic attendance based system

Tags: php, mysql

holla guys

i am midst of creating a php web apps where it allows admin to tick who have attended class.

i have following data on database

semester start date, semester end date, class day and time

for example,

`5 March 2012`, `9th April 2012` `Monday{9,12},Thursday{14,17}`

I can get total weeks based start and end date. Now the problem lies on how do i get the date which classes suppose to be, like on Monday, it suppose to be 9th, but on thursday? dynamically.

Is there any php classes or any approach?

Thanks alot

Comment: Why are you storing the data in this format: `Monday{9,12},Thursday{14,17}`???

Comment: Are you just asking how to dynamically extract the 14 and 17 from the string `Monday{9,12},Thursday{14,17}`? If so, use a regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do NOT implement date functions yourself, there are a lot of pitfalls when handling dates. You can use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) to iterate through the dates by using strings like: `strtotime("next Thursday", yourdate)`

Comment: thank you so much, ill try with this first and convert the date to unix_timestamp first.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if it's apt to change the format of your data at this point, but the way I would recommend structuring your database (which would vastly simplify querying the type of information you asking about) would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_attendance` (
  `student` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `class` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `attended` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student`,`class`)
)
```

Then, to query how many days a student attended, you would do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `student_attendance` 
WHERE `student` = '1'
AND `attended` = TRUE;
```

Of course, without knowing more about what exactly you're trying to accomplish, I can't be sure this is entirely appropriate.  Although the format you are using to store your data in seems like it will make your life needlessly difficult (you're combining different data points into a single column; that's a no-no), so I'd imagine this is an improvement.

EDIT: To be more precise, save the date and period (instead of the date and time); e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_attendance` (
  `student` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `class_period` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `attended` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student`,`class_date`,`class_period`)
)
```

Comment: erm, makes sense but the problem is that they can add few classes on different days and time, at that particular time i thought this would be the best way to go, but apparently not so now!

Comment: It might actually be easier to write a script that reformats your data, and then query that reformatted data. ;)